# Show that it is impossible to form a $20~\text{cm}$ length of wire into a rectangle with area $30~\text{cm}^2$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I do not know how to solve this issue. Can somebody please show me the steps needed in order to solve this question?

Comment: Your tag, "exponential function ", has no apparent connection to the problem.  Do you know basic calculus?

Comment: The maximum area is with the sides equal (ie a square), and you can show this by the algebraic procedure of "completing the square".

Answer (score 2):

Because $xy = 30$ and $x + y = 10$ have no real solution.

($x$ and $y$ are the length and breadth of a possible rectangle, if any)

You can show this using AM-GM inequality

Answer (score 2):

$x+y=10$, square: $x^2+2xy+y^2=100$

$x-y\in \mathbb{R}$, square: $x^2-2xy+y^2\ge 0$

Take the difference of these squares and ... uh-oh.

Comment: Oscar.oh-la-la.+1